# How do I calculate the negative-log likelihood of a linear regression model in r?

Tags: r, regression, linear, likelihood

I need to calculate the NLL of the regression and minimize it. How I can do this in R?

Comment: I visually inspected a scatterplot of the data and did not find a clear trend to be modeled. It might help to add more data points before regression, either by taking multiple measurements at the same temperatures to help reduce any noise, or by increasing the temperature range to clarify any possible trend, or both.